# ggplot2: creating a linear map (of transcription factor binding sites) consist with a line and filled boxes by using geom_segment and geom_text_repel

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a map of transcription factor binding sites on the promoter DNA sequence of some gene by using `ggplot2` with `geom_segment` and `geom_text_repel`.

This is a a snippet of my data:

```
mincle.tf <- structure(list(
  Matrix.ID = c(
    "MA0007.3", "PB0118.1", "MA0608.1",
    "MA0474.1", "MA0608.1", "MA0098.2", "MA0007.3", "PB0012.1"
  ),
  Name = structure(c(1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c(
    "Ar",
    "Creb3l2", "Elf3_1", "Erg", "Esrra_2", "Ets1"
  ), class = "factor"),
  Score = c(
    13.8552, 13.7763, 13.6251, 13.0501, 12.9081, 12.7074,
    12.6526, 12.4201
  ), Relative.score = c(
    0.8831708, 0.9177318,
    0.9736072, 0.9454676, 0.9613641, 0.8977955, 0.8696497, 0.9363881
  ), Sequence.ID = c(
    "seq1", "seq1", "seq1", "seq1", "seq1",
    "seq1", "seq1", "seq1"
  ), Start = c(
    603L, 505L, 28L, 873L,
    29L, 872L, 603L, 873L
  ), End = c(
    619L, 521L, 36L, 883L, 37L,
    886L, 619L, 885L
  ), Strand = c(
    "-", "+", "+", "-", "-", "+",
    "+", "-"
  ), Predicted.sequence = c(
    "gggaacataatgtgcat", "gtaaaggggtcagattc",
    "tccacgtgt", "agaggaaatga", "gacacgtgg", "atcatttcctctttt",
    "atgcacattatgttccc", "aaagaggaaatga"
  )
), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -8L
), class = "data.frame")
```

This is my code:

```
ggplot(mincle.tf, aes(Start, 3, label=Name)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=Start, y=3, xend=End, yend=3), size=10, data=mincle.tf[1:8], color=cbp2, alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 3, xend = 1200, yend = 3), size=1, color="black") + 
  geom_text_repel(data=mincle.tf[1:8],nudge_y = 0.1,point.padding = 0, box.padding = 0, direction = "x", angle=90, hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5)
```

This is the plot I get:

[image]

Basically, I am using `geom_segment` to draw a line of DNA (black) and colored boxes for TF binding sites, and using `geom_text_repel` to label each box according to the `Name` column in the data.

My issue is that the label lines start at the beginning of each box, instead of the center of the box, and I can't quite shorten the length of label lines by `point.padding` and `box.padding`. Also, some boxes overlap and I can't figure out the best way to show the overlap.  I tried with transparency but was not successful (see a figure below).

[image]

At this point, I would really appreciate any suggestions and pointers to make improvements in this plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To adress the last question first, one way to show overlapping features is to put disjoint ranged features into distinct bins. You can calculate this with Bioconductor's IRanges package.

```
mincle.tf$bin <- with(mincle.tf, IRanges::disjointBins(IRanges::IRanges(Start, End))) - 1
```

You can use the calculated bin as an offset from the y positions. Note below the `y = 3 + bin * 0.06`, wherein the `0.06` is simply a scaling factor that fits with the plot.

To put the labels in the middle of the TFBSs you can set the x-position to `(Start + End) / 2`.

The reason you didn't seem able to shorten the lines of the labels, is because essentially your entire plot had near-0 width (in dataspace) on the y-axis. Expanding the y-axis allows you to shorten the label lines.

```
ggplot(mincle.tf, aes(Start, 3, label=Name)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=Start, y=3 + bin * 0.06, 
                   xend=End, yend=3 + bin * 0.06, colour = Matrix.ID), 
               size=10, data=mincle.tf[1:8,], alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 3, xend = 1200, yend = 3), size=1, color="black") + 
  geom_text_repel(data=mincle.tf[1:8,],
                  aes(x = (Start + End) / 2,
                      y = 3 + bin * 0.06),
                  nudge_y = 0.1,
                  point.padding = 0, box.padding = 0.5, direction = "x", 
                  angle=90, hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(2.5, 3.5))
```

[image]

Note that for the example above I didn't have your `cbp2` variable so I substituted the PWM/PFM IDs (at least that is my guess what they are).

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I expanded mincle.tf ;

```
str(mincle.tf)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  49 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Matrix ID         : chr  "PB0093.1" "PB0093.1" "MA0608.1" "MA0626.1" ...
 $ Name              : chr  "Zfp105_1" "Zfp105_1" "Creb3l2" "Npas2" ...
 $ Score             : num  14.6 14.2 13.6 13.5 13 ...
 $ Relative score    : num  0.968 0.959 0.974 0.993 0.963 ...
 $ Sequence ID       : chr  "seq1" "seq1" "seq1" "seq1" ...
 $ Start             : int  708 705 28 28 205 29 29 205 616 616 ...
 $ End               : int  722 719 36 37 215 37 36 215 627 627 ...
 $ Strand            : chr  "+" "+" "+" "+" ...
 $ Predicted sequence: chr  "aaaaaacaacaagaa" "aacaaaaaacaacaa" "tccacgtgt" "tccacgtgtc" ...
 $ bin               : num  1 0 2 3 0 4 0 1 1 2 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "index")= int(0) 
  ..- attr(*, "__Strand")= int [1:49] 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 12 16 ...
```

and have made a few changes to the ggplot 2 script as follows

```
    mycolors <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Set2"))(27)
    ggplot(mincle.tf, aes(Start, 3, label=Name, color=Name)) 
        +geom_segment(aes(x=-Start, y=2.8, xend=-End, yend=2.8), size=10, data=mincle.tf[Strand=="-" & Score > 9], alpha=0.5)
        +geom_segment(aes(x=-Start, y=3.2, xend=-End, yend=3.2), size=10, data=mincle.tf[Strand=="+" & Score > 9], alpha=0.5)
        +scale_color_manual(values = mycolors)+geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 3, xend = -1000, yend = 3), size=1, color="black")
        +geom_text_repel(data=mincle.tf[Strand=="+" & Score > 9],aes(-Start, 3.2), nudge_y = 0.15, point.padding = 0.8, box.padding = 0.8, direction = "x", angle=90, hjust=0.5, vjust=1)
        +geom_text_repel(data=mincle.tf[Strand=="-" & Score > 9],aes(-Start, 2.8), nudge_y = -0.1, point.padding = 0.5, box.padding = 0.5, direction = "x", angle=90, hjust=0.5, vjust=1)+ylim(2.5, 3.5)
        +geom_segment(aes(x=-pos, y=2.98, xend=-pos, yend=3.02), size=0.5, color="black", data = dt3, inherit.aes = FALSE)
        +annotate("text", x=-dt3$pos, y=2.95, label=-dt3$pos, size=3)
        +annotate("text", x=-500, y=2.55, label="- Strand", size=6)
            +guides(color = FALSE, size = FALSE)+annotate("text", x=-500, y=3.45, label="+ Strand", size=6)
            +guides(color = FALSE, size = FALSE)+theme_void()
```

A resulting map of TF within the promoter sequence in question is following;
[image]

I am interested in only TFBS(predicted score) > 9 and separated TFs based on whether they bind + or - strand.

I incorporated @teunbrand's suggestion to generate "bins" by using IRange to stack up overlapping TF binding sites as follows;

```
ggplot(mincle.tf, aes(Start, 3, label=Name, color=Name)) 
+geom_segment(aes(x=-Start, y=2.6+bin*0.03, xend=-End, yend=2.6+bin*0.03), size=10, data=mincle.tf[Strand=="-" & Score > 9], alpha=0.5)
+geom_segment(aes(x=-Start, y=3.2+bin*0.06, xend=-End, yend=3.2+bin*0.06), size=10, data=mincle.tf[Strand=="+" & Score > 9], alpha=0.5)
+scale_color_manual(values = mycolors)+geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 3, xend = -1000, yend = 3), size=1, color="black")
+geom_text_repel(data=mincle.tf[Strand=="+" & Score > 9],aes(-Start, 3.2), nudge_y = 0.15, point.padding = 0.8, box.padding = 0.8, direction = "x", angle=90, hjust=0.5, vjust=1)
+geom_text_repel(data=mincle.tf[Strand=="-" & Score > 9],aes(-Start, 2.6+bin*0.03), nudge_y = -0.1, point.padding = 0.5, box.padding = 0.5, direction = "x", angle=90, hjust=0.5, vjust=1)+ylim(2.5, 3.5)
+geom_segment(aes(x=-pos, y=2.98, xend=-pos, yend=3.02), size=0.5, color="black", data = dt3, inherit.aes = FALSE)
+annotate("text", x=-dt3$pos, y=2.95, label=-dt3$pos, size=3)
+annotate("text", x=-500, y=2.1, label="- Strand", size=6)
+guides(color = FALSE, size = FALSE)+annotate("text", x=-500, y=3.6, label="+ Strand", size=6)
+guides(color = FALSE, size = FALSE)+theme_void()
```

and a resulting plot is as follows;

[image]

I still have to make a few mods to make it look better but it looks pretty decent.  @teunbrand, I really appreciate your help.